# Comparison or limit comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\ln n)^3}{n+9}$$

How would I use the comparison test or the limit comparison test to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from two terms at the beginning, $\ln n > 1$ so $(\ln n)^3>1$ and hence we use comparison test to get  $$\frac{(\ln n)^3}{n+9}>\frac{1}{n+9}$$

Now, you use limit comparison between $\sum\frac{1}{n+9}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.